# How does java differentiate two keys in KV instance in apache beam?

Tags: java, apache-beam

Version of apache beam is `2.15.0` .

In this [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/data-science-on-gcp/blob/master/04_streaming/realtime/chapter4/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/training/flights/AverageDelayPipeline.java) , class *Airport* is used as Key for KV instance and at the end, *mean* is calculated for each *Airport* instance .

```
c.output(KV.of(stats.airport, stats.timestamp));
```

But how does *apache beam* internally compare two keys and return if two instances are same or not ? Are two instances treated same if all the class members has same values ? [Document](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.15.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/values/KV.html) does not mention about the comparison for two keys.

I appreciate if someone can help me out with understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually explained in the `GroupByKey` transform [docs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.15.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/GroupByKey.html), which is the operation done under the hood for a `Mean` aggregation:

> Two keys of type `K` are compared for equality **not** by regular Java
>   `Object.equals`(`java.lang.Object`), but instead by first encoding each of
>   the keys using the `Coder` of the keys of the input `PCollection`, and
>   then comparing the encoded bytes. This admits efficient parallel
>   evaluation. Note that this requires that the `Coder` of the keys be
>   deterministic (see [`Coder.verifyDeterministic()`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.15.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/Coder.html#verifyDeterministic--)). If the key `Coder` is
>   not deterministic, an exception is thrown at pipeline construction
>   time.

Note that [`Mean`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.15.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Mean.html) uses [`Combine.PerKey`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.15.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.PerKey.html) which is a 'shorthand' for `GroupByKey` + `Combine.GroupedValues`.

Comment: Fantastic ! Thank you for taking your time.